# Trying to override Nokogiri's serializing behaviour

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to alter an HTML tree and output the code. I need to alter the way a particular node outputs to html (details below), so I've subclassed `Nokogiri::XML::Node`.

How do I override that subclass' output behaviour?

Right now, if I override `to_html()`, then I get the display I want when calling `to_html()` for instances of `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment`, but when I call it on instances of `Nokogiri::HTML::Document`, the normal output behaviour takes over.  That won't do because I actually need to make changes to the document head (which is excluded from DocumentFragment instances).

**Why I need to alter the HTML output:**

I need to be able to include an unpartnered `</noscript>` tag for the sake of using GWO with my code. However, I can't add an unpartnered end tag in an HTML tree.

With Nokogiri, I can't add it as text either because the `<` and `>` get escaped as html char codes.

I can't use Hpricot for this project because I'm running it over some bad code (written by others at work), and Hpricot won't preserve the errors in question (like putting a block element inside of an `<a>` element). (No, I'm not about to track down all the bad HTML and fix it.)

**Specs:** WinXP, Ruby 1.8.6, Nokogiri 1.4.4

**Update:**

For a reason I can't guess, when I create a constructor for my subclass, regardless of how many parameters I require for the subclass constructor, I get errors if I supply any number but two (the number of params required for the superclass).

```
class NoScript < Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def initialize(doc)
    super("string", doc)
  end
end
```

I haven't had this problem with other classes.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your code is calling at some point [`write_to`](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb#L806) (`to_html` calls `serialize`, and `serialize` calls `write_to`). It then calls [`native_write_to`](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb#L821) on current node. Let's take a look at it.

```
static VALUE native_write_to(
    VALUE self,
    VALUE io,
    VALUE encoding,
    VALUE indent_string,
    VALUE options
) {
  xmlNodePtr node;
  const char * before_indent;
  xmlSaveCtxtPtr savectx;

  Data_Get_Struct(self, xmlNode, node);

  xmlIndentTreeOutput = 1;

  before_indent = xmlTreeIndentString;

  xmlTreeIndentString = StringValuePtr(indent_string);

  savectx = xmlSaveToIO(
      (xmlOutputWriteCallback)io_write_callback,
      (xmlOutputCloseCallback)io_close_callback,
      (void *)io,
      RTEST(encoding) ? StringValuePtr(encoding) : NULL,
      (int)NUM2INT(options)
  );

  xmlSaveTree(savectx, node);
  xmlSaveClose(savectx);

  xmlTreeIndentString = before_indent;
  return io;
}
```

Code is in [github](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/blob/master/ext/nokogiri/xml_node.c#L1017). If you read it, you will see that it does not call your to_html anywhere, so your custom method is never run. OTOH, if you use a `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment` it is being called, because [`DocumentFragment#to_html`](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/xml/document_fragment.rb#L42) relies on [`Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet#to_html`](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb#L275) and it is a plain map:

```
def to_html *args
  if Nokogiri.jruby?
    options = args.first.is_a?(Hash) ? args.shift : {}
    if !options[:save_with]
      options[:save_with] = Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION | Node::SaveOptions::NO_EMPTY_TAGS | Node::SaveOptions::AS_HTML
    end
    args.insert(0, options)
  end
  map { |x| x.to_html(*args) }.join
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I've looked through the code, but I don't see any way of altering what gets rendered by `serialize`. (I even looked at the source for `native_write_to`. It looks like the field `cstruct` would be the crucial one, but I can't figure out how to access it or what it is.) Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is for internal use. This means that, if you need to add the `</noscript>` I would add it as text and then use gsub.